# Can Electron waves undergo Polarisation just like Light?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, optics, electromagnetic-radiation, quantum-electrodynamics

Here electron waves refers to the matter wave of electrons as proposed by De-Broglie hypothesis.

Comment: What is an "electron wave"? Do you mean the quantum-mechanical *wavefunction*? What would "polarization" mean in that context?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Photon spin is a two-state system, and optical polarization is directly related to coherent photon spins. Electron spin is also a two-state system, and so much of the math for describing polarized electron beams is the same as for polarized photon beams.

The analogy is not perfect. The photon is a  spin-one system which follows the two-state algebra because the spin-zero projection is forbidden. A photon beam with spin axis parallel to its momentum is circularly polarized. Linear-polarized light is a coherent mixture of left- and right-circular polarizations, with the polarization direction determined by the relative phase. But there is no way to produce "up-polarized" light: the orthogonal bases are vertical/horizontal and diagonal/diagonal.

For an electron beam,  however, you can point the spin axis in any direction in space. There is no way to make a "plane-polarized" electron beam; electrons polarized so their north poles point "up" are orthogonal to electrons whose north poles point "down."

Comment: I feel this isn't a good analogy because the projection of spin onto momentum (=polarization/helicity) is a Lorentz invariant for photons, but not an invariant for massive particles like the electron

Comment: No, it’s not a Lorentz invariant. But it’s still useful if you choose a reference frame. For example, the polarized electron accelerator at JLab generally sends pure-helicity beams to the parity-violation experiments for most of the data-taking, then sends some transverse-polarized beam to measure the much larger parity-allowed scattering for background corrections. That machine has constraints on what polarizations it can deliver when there are multiple experiments using the beam, because of the way the electron spins precess in the accelerator. Spin precession is also a factor in muon $g-2$.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know about "all properties of em waves", but electron spin (projection) is at least an analog of light polarization, and spin projection is a property of electron waves.